Dropdown Filter Issue with R Plot_ly Plots
I've been having an issue with update menus functionality within r's plot_ly package.
An approach that has previously worked for chloropleth figures doesn't seem to work when applied to a stacked bar chart and I am unable to ascertain as to why this is happening.
Example code:
library(plotly)

# Simplified data frame for testing
test_data <- data.frame(
  time = rep(1:10, each = 4),
  total = rnorm(40, 100, 10),
  Species_name = rep(c("Species A", "Species B", "Species C", "Species D"), 10),
  mesh_grp = rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2"), 20)
)

p <- test_data %>%
  plot_ly(
          x = ~time, 
          y = ~total, 
          split = ~Species_name, 
          color =~Species_name, 
          type = 'bar', 
    transforms = list(
      list(
        type = 'filter',
        target = ~mesh_grp,
        operation = '=',
        value = unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[1]
      )
  )) %>% layout(
    barmode = "stack",
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        type = 'dropdown',
        active = 0,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[1]),
               label = unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[1]),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[2]),
               label = unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[2])
        )
      )
    )
  )

p

In the above I would expect the dropdown menu for "Group 1" to filter the data to include results from Species "A" and "C". However, the result includes all species and only data for time periods that fall on odd numbers (see image). Group 1 Group 2
Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?
Many thanks in advance! :)

You can achieve your desired result by re-arranging your data. (I figured this out by inspecting the plotly object via plotly_json). Would have expected that plotly takes care of that and hence it looks like a bug to me.
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)

test_data %>%
  arrange(Species_name, mesh_grp) %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~time,
    y = ~total,
    split = ~Species_name,
    color = ~Species_name,
    type = "bar",
    transforms = list(
      list(
        type = "filter",
        target = ~mesh_grp,
        operation = "=",
        value = unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[1]
      )
    )
  ) %>%
  layout(
    barmode = "stack",
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        type = "dropdown",
        active = 0,
        buttons = list(
          list(
            method = "restyle",
            args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[1]),
            label = unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[1]
          ),
          list(
            method = "restyle",
            args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[2]),
            label = unique(test_data$mesh_grp)[2]
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )



Thanks for coming back to me on this @Stefan. The above approach still only posts data from every other "time" period (i.e odd time periods only 1,3,5 etc.). Any idea how to include the even time periods too? Thanks!

Aw. Thx for clarifying. Now I understand what's the issue and on further inspection I think that I figured out what's the problem, i.e. we simply have to re-arrange the dataset. See my updated and edited post.
